# How to use try catch

Tags: php, database, laravel, try-catch

I'm trying to make a catch try this:

```
Config::set( 'database.connections.information_schema', array ( 
    'driver'     =>  'mysql', 
    'host'       =>  'localhost', 
    'port'       =>  '3306', 
    'database'   =>  'information_schema', 
    'username'   =>  'root', 
    'password'   =>  '1', 
    'charset'    =>  'utf8', 
    'collation'  =>  'utf8_unicode_ci', 
    'prefix'     =>  ''
    // 'strict'    => false, 
)); 

try 
{
    $datos = DB::connection('information_schema')->getDatabaseName();    
    echo "Conectado correctamente a la base de datos: ".$datos.".";
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo 'Error';
}
```

And when he goes right ejectua the try but obviously when to go for the catch does not show echo

Comment: What is exactly your problem? You think it never enter the catch when an error happen?

Comment: Here is a good example on how to use try catch block for php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549584/how-to-efficiently-use-try-catch-blocks-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your

```
catch (Exception $e)
```

to

```
catch (\Exception $e)
```

More info on [importing/aliasing namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php); you can also add `use Exception;` in the top of the file. Find more in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Answer (score -1):

I suppose the database connection is in some function/method. If it is not, just put the code in some function.

In case of error, we jump out of the function with `return` command and continue only if the code inside of `try` block succeeded.

Something like this:

```
...
try {
    $datos = DB::connection('information_schema')->getDatabaseName();    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error';
    return false;
}
//connected successfully
echo "Conectado correctamente a la base de datos: ".$datos.".";
...
```