# Sudden SQL problem - General error: 1364 Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, sql

So I have a list of servers as a website - out of no where - when you try to add a new server it gives an error -

> Array ( [success] => [error-codes] => Array ( [0] =>
>   missing-input-secret ) ) Unhandled Exception.  SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: 1364 Field 'ServerVotes' doesn't have a default value
>   You can find the error back in the log.

I went ahead and set a default value for it in phpymadmin, it asked for default values of more things - and after I set it it gave me some problems with the database. Any ideas what could be the source of this issue and where I could try to fix it?

Comment: All I've done is try to set the phpmyadmin default value, but it just says some other stuff dont have default values, and then some problems with the database. I just want help where I could possibly find the error log or how to fix something like this.

Comment: We need to know "other stuff" and "more things". Are these date columns by any chance?

Comment: Well, what are the problems with the database? What did you do to cause this? Did you try to install a new version of your php software?

Comment: the more things are literally the same. instead of servervotes, it says serverrank, and some SAME stuff with the SAME error. And what do you mean by date columns?

Comment: And I did nothing. One day it just popped.

Comment: Do you use MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

The source of your problem is your MySQL version has been updated to 5.7 (or above) or otherwise is now using "**SQL Strict**" mode, so as the name implies, you are needing to update the way your data is set, so it fits the strict criteria.

1)
A (unwise) work around is to [change your MYSQL settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374335/error-in-mysql-when-setting-default-value-for-date-or-datetime) on the server to *TURN OFF STRICT MODE* (temporarily) and then correct your data to fit the new strict mode, before turning it back on.

Typically, [Strict Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) (*[good reading material](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/18/upgrading-to-mysql-5-7-beware-of-the-new-strict-mode/)*) includes:

- Empty values should be `null`
- Invalid dates **MUST** be `null`
- **All** values should have a `default` setting (*this is your error*).
- Data longer than the column row length will now result in a failed insert rather than a cut off (Example: inserted data is 20 chrs and the column length is `VARCHAR(15)`). Therefore column lengths must be checked before insert/update.
- GROUP BY has got a lot more fiddly.

2) 
 
You can also look up This specific [MySQL Error Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751291/mysql-error-1364-field-display-name-doesnt-have-default-value) and that will guide you to resolve this issue.

3) 
Further, you need to properly [handle the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549584/how-to-efficiently-use-try-catch-blocks-in-php) that this causes, in your PHP database interface class / code.

4) 
You may get more information from your [MySQL Error log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145627/error-log-location) and possibly your [PHP Error Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel).

Comment: Unfortunately after talking to the host, I'm unable to remove the strict mode of SQL. I went ahead and sell the default value of all the empty ones and the next error I've encountered - Array ( [success] => [error-codes] => Array ( [0] => missing-input-secret ) ) Unhandled Exception. 
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `database`.`servers`.`VotifierPort` at row 1
You can find the error back in the log.

Comment: @RobertPringe You want to keep strict mode, it's better, but you need to conform to it.